# An external system web page resizing issue on an iPad

Tags: salesforce1-app

We added a connected app into the VF page.
The connected app is being used for loading the external system.
Below is the VF page screenshot:

[image]

Everything seems to be working correctly, however the external system web pages are not resized correctly inside the Salesforce1 app on an iPad.

Any ideas about what can be done to have the external system web pages correct resizes on an iPad?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more investigation I figured out that the resizing issue is causing because of iframe and some additional CSS classes inside the Salesforce1 context. We tried a lot of things to solve it, but unfortunately none of them helped us so finally we decided to do JavaScript top redirection from the external system once a user logs in the external system successfully as a result no iframe and no any CSS classes added by SFDC and it works as expected. Of course, there were some security issues which we fixed as well.

Comment: I am facing the similar issue. Salesforce1 is resizing the external iframe forcefully on iphone and the iframe website becomes irresponsive. I didn't get the solution you mentioned. What did you redirect to where?